# Why does my event tracking code work in the console, but not when I install it onto the website?

Tags: google-analytics

This is the code I have

```
jQuery('iframe.language-menu-frame').contents().find(".text").click(function(){
    if (ga) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Language Tool', 'click');
    }
});
```

I placed this code inside my js file along with other event tracking code. All the other event tracking code works just fine, but not this one. Any idea why it is working in the console but not when installed into the js file?

Comment: my guess is the iframe probably doesn't exist or isn't fully loaded when your code executes

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your code, or log something to the console to ensure that code is actually running?

Comment: @CrayonViolent could be, I'll check the load order.

Comment: @PhilipWalton I'll try to log out something